# Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null in JSF2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am quite new to JSF and I have this problem. I was reading some posts about that but I could found answer( or I didnt understood one...).
I have following user bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable {

    private String login;


    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
}
```

and login bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="login")
@SessionScoped
public class Login implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManagedProperty("#{user}")
    private User user;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Init called");
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And my view looks like this:

```
<h:inputText id="login" value="#{login.user.login}" required="true"/>
<h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{login.user.login}"/><br/>
```

I want access to user fields in few classess and this how I am trying to achieve this. Unfortunately I keep got this error.
I have found some information that I need `beans.xml`. Is that true? Where can I find sample? I am using JSF2.

**Answer**
My fault was that I choose same name for field and for login method. Because of that I was using `login.login`( before implementing User class) for geting login, and `login.login` as a action of `commandButton`. After I implemented User class I changed both `login.login` to `login.user.login`.
 Thanks again for help.

Comment: You getting the error when clicking the button ?

Comment: Yes. Page loads correctly. Problem occurs after clicking the button.

Comment: The input text works fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding a method `User#login()` to your `CommandButton`, which does not exist. There is only a property `login` (get/set).

You need a proper action method in your `User` bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped
public class User implements Serializable {

    private String login;


    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public void doLogin() { 
        // whatever you want to do here
    }
}
```

and bind to the `doLogin()` method:

```
<h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{login.user.doLogin}"/>
```

`beans.xml` is required to enable CDI, which you don't use here. You are using jsf managed beans. CDI is a more powerful alternative.